# Как получить содержимое страницы, которая грузится через AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, http, парсер

Получить содержимое страницы на PHP.
Раньше я делал это достаточно легко через file_get_contents( $url ). Но на одном сайте список товаров грузится ajax-om, точнее ангуляром.
    То есть если открыть такую страницу в браузере, у вас будет крутиться лоадер и через некоторе время появятся товары.

Функция file_get_contents( $url ) получает сырой код, то есть типа

```
<div class="spisok" data-ng-repeat="tovar in models.tovari">
<span>
 {{tovari.name}}
</span><br/>
</div>
```

Как получить обработанное( загруженное ) содержимое страницы?

Comment: Смотрите, какой запрос делает браузер, чтобы получить эти данные и делайте аналогичный из php.

Comment: На английском стеке уже ответили:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505501/get-the-content-text-of-an-url-after-javascript-has-run-with-php

Comment: php код в студию

Answer (score 1):

Вам может помочь [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).
Через метод evaluate вы получите контекст загруженной страницы, а дальше можете либо качать всю страницу, либо весь арсенал JS селекторов у вас в руках. Пример взят с офф. сайта:

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://m.bing.com', function(status) {

  var title = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.title;
  });

  console.log(title);
  phantom.exit();

});
```

Comment: а ваш код не работает =(

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут же все тоже самое загружаете инструмент разработчика , в любом браузере . В хроме и ему подобных (опера , яндекс , рамблер итд) он встроеный в мозиле firebug 
смотрите что грузится у вас после загрузки страницы , берете этот url подставляете свои параметры и тем же file_get_contents качаете контент
[image: пример]

Comment: не прокатить. уже пробовал. Вместо содержимого просто вовращается false

Comment: Ну оно и понятно , вы смотрели каким методом выполнен ajax запрос ?  если POST то file_get_contents не отработает и тут только CURL. мало информации даете .

Comment: Открываете консоль и поочередно отправляете запросы на GET и POST тот что даст результат и является искомым протоколом $.post("тут ваш url") или $.get("тут ваш url")

Comment: Похоже я просто передаю неправильный урл. Можно ли через интсрументы разработчика понять куда передаются параметры от angular.js?

Comment: я же написал Вам выше , берете урл по которому уходит запрос и проверяете его . angular.js тут не причем , ничего хитрого он де делает . дайте адрес от куда вы хотите спарсить .

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключиться через curl к нужной странице, должно сработать, например:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                                         
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$data = curl_exec($curl)
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Неа. Получаешь сырой HTML код
что то типа {{tovari.name}} вместо названия товаров

Comment: Такой код напрямую нельзя получать и открывать у себя в браузере. Ты создаёшь клиента-робота и подход тут другой. Берешь $data и с помощью SimpleHTML DOM дальше пилишь. Все это возможно. А если откроешь $data у себя в браузере то это уже кроссдоменный запрос, который может криво работать. Приходилось парсить сайт, где ajax подгружалось абсолютно всё. Прошло всё успешно.

Answer (score 0):

В хроме я использую расширение https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-source-viewer/cfmcghennfbpmhemnnfjhkdmnbidpanb?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

После загрузки страницы и отработки скриптов можно посмотреть результат со всеми изменениями.

Comment: А инструмент разработчика Хром - разве не тоже самое делает ?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью библиотеки CURL это возможно. Недавно сайт парсил где все на ajax и с библиотекой jQuery. Так если парсишь с помощью curl и потом выводим в браузер, то будет все криво, потому-что клиент в данный момент CURL(сервер), а не Вы. Кроссдоменный запрос не прокатит поэтому нужно взять к примеру библиотеку Simple HTMLDOM

```
$curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // times out after 4s
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return into a variable
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ya.ru/");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 GTB6");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
```

Выводить $data не нужно. Всё, ваш клиент (сервер) получил страницу. Теперь скачиваем http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ И есть инструкция например здесь http://zubuntu.ru/php-simple-html-dom-parser/
То есть нам нужно продолжить так:

```
$html=str_get_html($data);
$result=$html->find(div.spisok span); //получаем массив
```

Дальше его перебираем.

```
foreach ($result as $one){
   echo $one; //можем уже выводить то, что нашли
}
```

По такому принципу ищем данные, перебираем их. Важно точно определить "координаты" данных.