# Авторизация на сайте Ria.com

Tags: php, jquery, yii, curl, https

Есть сайт, на котором я зарегистрирован как пользователь - [RIA](https://www.ria.com/)
Данный сайт работает на протоколе HTTPS/HSTS.

Для того, чтобы войти в систему, надо пройти авторизацию на [странице](https://www.ria.com/index/login).

Форма вызывается с фрейма [ссылке](https://login.ria.com/login/1/2), соответственно запросы обрабатывает тот же адрес.

Есть значение под атрибутом *hidden*:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="ключ">
```

Авторизацию я пытаюсь провести следующим образом:

```
$login_form =  file_get_contents('https://login.ria.com/login/1/2');
preg_match_all('|<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="(.+?)">|is', $login_form, $data);

$cUrl = curl_init('https://login.ria.com/');
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.ria.com/login/1/2');
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "_csrf={$data[1][0]}&EmailLoginForm[email]=380666640744&EmailLoginForm[password]=duxumucuc");
$result = curl_exec($cUrl);
```

В ответ я получаю `bool(true)`, даже если пароль неверный.

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать и можно ли вообще что-то сделать?

Требуется добавлять объявления без прямого входа в аккаунт. **API** у них нет.

**UPD I:**

Вот какбы проходит авторизация, но возвращает мне следующее:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: nginx Date: Mon, 28 Sep 2015 14:12:23 GMT Content-Type: text/html Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.18 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache
```

Тут уже не знаю что делать.

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть на комментарии и ответы к этому вопросу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453400/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax

Comment: @Visman, на то время я дубом был в РНР, а тем более в NodeJS :) За полтора года коммерции - как-то более стал разбираться в том, что делаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Csrf токен привязывается к сессии, нужно сохранять cookies от первого запроса и делать второй с ними. Я бы порекомендовал использовать guzzle, в нем есть все для парсинга.

Примера авторизации в github с помощью [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) и [goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte), сессии обрабатываются автоматически, так что за ними не надо следить

1. Установка зависимостей

   ```
   composer require fabpot/goutte
   ```
2. Скрипт

   ```
   use Goutte\Client;
   $client = new Client();
   //открываем страницу с формой
   $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://github.com/login');
   //находим форму
   $form = $crawler->selectButton('Sign in')->form();
   //отправляем ее
   $crawler = $client->submit($form, array('login'=>'user','password'=>'password'));
   //теперь уже как авторизованный юзер ходим по гитхабу
   $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://github.com/pulls');
   echo $crawler->html();
   ```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую данный метод.

Comment: Что-то не получается у меня интегрировать Guzzle в проект.

Comment: @RomanKozin Сделал пример скрипта